# Testing with Mocha and Chai consuming values from previous tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I have some tests created with `mocha` and `chai` using `TypeScript`, they actually work as expected. Each function returns a `Promise` which runs a `test`.

My question is if is there anyway to consume on each `test` the value returned by a previous `test` without using the nesting you see below.

My concern is that if I have more `test` the nesting code could be very annoying going to the right

```
import * as request from 'supertest';
import app from '../src/app';
import { Promise } from 'bluebird';
import * as dateformat from 'dateformat';
import Commons from '../../utils/commons';
import { expect } from 'chai';

...
// all the functions used below are defined over here
...

registerNonExistingUser(email, pass, role).then(
    (jwtToken: string) => {
        authenticateUserCorrectJwt(jwtToken).then(
            (user) => {
                authenticateUserWrongJwt().then(
                    () => {
                        loginUserWrongCredentials().then(
                            () => {
                                loginUserCorrectCredentials(email, pass).then(
                                    (jwtToken: string) => {
                                        getLocalUserInfoCorrectJwt(jwtToken, email).then(
                                            (user) => {
                                                createTodoAsEditor(jwtToken, todoTitle).then(
                                                    (todos) => {
                                                        checkTodoExistsWithCorrectTitle(jwtToken, todoTitle).then(
                                                            (todo: any) => {
                                                                deleteTodoWithCorrectIdAsEditor(jwtToken, todo._id).then(
                                                                    (todo) => {
                                                                        unregisterExistingUser({
                                                                            'local.email': email,
                                                                        }).then(
                                                                            (user) => {
                                                                                // console.log(Commons.stringify(user));
                                                                            }
                                                                        );
                                                                    }
                                                                );
                                                            }
                                                        );
                                                    }
                                                );
                                            }
                                        );
                                    }
                                );
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Any idea on how to beautify this?

**[EDIT 1]**

[@bhoo-day](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375148/bhoo-day) suggestion did the trick:

```
registerNonExistingUser(email, pass, role)
    .then((_jwtToken: string) => { 
        return authenticateUserCorrectJwt(_jwtToken);
    })
    .then((user) => {
        return authenticateUserWrongJwt();
    })
    ...
```

Now I'm wondering if I could transform the beginning of the chain, in order to be something like the following (which I tried but doesn't work). My goal is to put every function at the same level, including the very first function:

```
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => { 
        return registerNonExistingUser(email, pass, role);
    })
    .then((jwtToken: string) => { 
        return authenticateUserCorrectJwt(jwtToken);
    })
    .then((user) => {
        return authenticateUserWrongJwt();
    })
    ...
```

**[EDIT 2]**

I tried the following and it works. Do you have any idea on how to simplify it?, maybe using: `Promise.resolve()...`?

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
    it('dummy', (done) => { resolve(); return done(); });
})
.then(() => { 
    return registerNonExistingUser(email, pass, role);
})
.then((_jwtToken: string) => { 
    return authenticateUserCorrectJwt(_jwtToken);
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use promise, you could avoid this callback hell because that is the main purpose of promise.

Some ideas to solve the issue.

```
// temp variable to store jwt token
let token;

registerNonExistingUser(email, pass, role)
  .then((jwtToken: string) => { 
    token = jwtToken; // assign it so other functions can use it
    return authenticateUserCorrectJwt(jwtToken)
  })
  .then((user) => authenticateUserWrongJwt())
  .then(() => loginUserWrongCredentials())
  .then(() => loginUserCorrectCredentials(email, pass))
  .then((jwtToken: string) => getLocalUserInfoCorrectJwt(jwtToken, email))
  .then((user) => createTodoAsEditor(token, todoTitle))
  .then((todos) => checkTodoExistsWithCorrectTitle(token, todoTitle))
  .then((todo: any) => deleteTodoWithCorrectIdAsEditor(token, todo._id))
  .then((todo) => unregisterExistingUser({ 'local.email': email }))
  .then((user) => {
    // console.log(Commons.stringify(user));
  });
```

or if you use node 7.6.0 or higher, you can use async/await. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

```
async function printUser() {    
    try { 
      let jwtToken = await registerNonExistingUser(email, pass, role);
      const user = await authenticateUserCorrectJwt(jwtToken);

      await loginUserWrongCredentials();
      jwtToken = await loginUserCorrectCredentials(email, pass);
      const user = await getLocalUserInfoCorrectJwt(jwtToken, email);
      const todos = await createTodoAsEditor(token, todoTitle);
      const todo = await checkTodoExistsWithCorrectTitle(token, todoTitle)

      const todo = await deleteTodoWithCorrectIdAsEditor(token, todo._id);
      const user = await unregisterExistingUser({ 'local.email': email });

      console.log(Commons.stringify(user));
    } catch (error) {
      // catch error here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @bhoo-day, your suggestion did the trick. Do you have maybe one suggestion for the question I just added on my edition above?

Comment: @davidesp that is supposed to work with your `Promise.resolve().then` solution. Can you do breakpoint using debugger or add `console.log` there?

Comment: when using: `Promise.resolve()` I added a breakpoint on the first `return` and the debugger stops there, but at the same time the testing finalizes right away. Then when I continue the debugging, it doesn't stop on the second `return` (I think the execution finalized or jumps to the end). In the other, if I use your version, when it stops on the first `return` the testing doesn't finalize yet, the I can continue pressing `F5` to jump from `return` to `return` as expected.

Comment: Perhaps we can try with `return Promise.resolve().then` or use `done()` at the last function from mocha https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: I just added **[EDIT 2]** with one working example. Do you think we could simplify it?, please, check above. Thanks!